# Oracle SQL XML file error recognising certain characters

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, encoding, tags

I'm trying to figure out why when I open up my XML file which I've processed I get the below message, all the tags seem to be in the correct place but after about 50 records, I get the below message, It seems to fall over on characters like '@'.

```
    </Production>
  </Message>
- <Message>
  <messageSequenceId>14</messageSequenceId> 
  <messageSequenceId>22742953</messageSequenceId> 
  <messageType>NEW</messageType> 
   <otherInformation>MIGRATION FIRST DELIVERY</otherInformation> 
- <The XML page cannot be displayed 
   Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later. 


 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  An invalid character was found in text content. Error processing resource 'file://data2/data/Download/d7prdv1/prsrepreports...

    <title>BRIS 3820 - VAUXHALL - INSIGNIAS @A

 Production>
  <prodCategoryType>EPISODE</prodCategoryType> 
  <prodStatusType>SKELETON</prodStatusType>
```

I noticed at the top of the file the XML header is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

where the example file I'm trying to replicate has the below at the beginning.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Could this have anything to do with my error? I'm working on an Oracle 11g database.

The start and end of my select is

```
     SELECT XMLSERIALIZE (
               DOCUMENT XMLROOT (
                           XMLELEMENT ("AV-XML",

                           database colums.......

             ), -- end AV-XML                                                                       
       VERSION '1.0') AS CLOB)  AS XMLRESULT
       INTO     l_clob
       FROM     productions prod, creations cre
      WHERE     prod.cre_surr_id = cre.surr_id(+)
```

Comment: Looks like you're using XSLT to transform the file ( or your SQL statement is ) and it trips over the @ because that is the attribute selector in XSLT. So I'd guess you'd need to escape your data for that ( somehow - that piece I cannot help with. )

Comment: [XMLSerialise](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions252.htm) les you specify the encoding and version (not sure you need XMLRoot here); but I doubt that's relevant.

Comment: Thanks guys, I've made the change but I'm still coming up with the error, I think it might be something simple that I'm doing wrong. Thanks so much for your help, I'll take another look at what I've done.